# Send all incoming URL request's through 1 file, getting Path Parameters for PHP

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, sef

I want the majority of the incoming URL requests to point to a global processorfile

```
**www.itsme.com/index.php**
```

The URL's can have all sort of structures but always with '/' instead of '?|&|=', eg

- www.itsme.com/news/finance/
- www.itsme.com/news/money/trading
- www.itsme.com/sports

The index.php should be able to recognize the URL and its parameters it has been called from, eg

```
array{[1]=>news,[2]=>finance})
```

Since i have many directories i want to better avoid placing in every one a (.htaccess) file seperately to do the redirect.

Apache / Linux / PHP 5.3

How could this be done?thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So easy it was. Placing this 1-liner in root as .htaccess will do:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [NC]
```

isn't it great?

Answer (score 0):

Have Apache do the work for you with `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/$ /index.php?parts[]=news&parts[]=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?parts[]=news&parts[]=$1&parts[]=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^sports/(.*)/$ /index.php?parts[]=sports&parts[]=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thx, i would prefer not to rewrite all url's (400 directories). isn't there one "do-all-except-those"? Greets